# Nginx gives a FormatMessage() error out-of-the-box on windows 10

Tags: nginx, windows-10

I'm having trouble setting up nginx 1.13.5 on windows 10.

I downloaded the windows binary from the nginx site.
I ran the executable using the example config file and got the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (10013: FormatMessage() error:(15100))
```

Google turned up empty.

No matter what I do the error doesn't go away and I cannot find any information about it.

I checked if anything was running on port 80 but nothing is.

Comment: Two possibilities of this issue, not enough privileges or something already running on port 80. Skype also at times interferes on port 80. So run it with admin rights and check if something else listening on port 80

Answer (score 0):

I had a windows process (WAS) using port 80. Shutting it down fixed it.